# Can't access javascript function from python through eel

Tags: javascript, python, eel

I've been trying to learn the basics of Eel through their documentation. I struggled learning how to trigger a javascript function through python so I tried to download their Hello World example straight from their github. [You can open it here.](https://github.com/python-eel/Eel/tree/master/examples/01%20-%20hello_world)

But I still get the same error, namely: **Exception has occurred: AttributeError
module 'eel' has no attribute 'say_hello_js'**

The code is as following: (you can also look it up on github in the link abov)

**hello.py**

```py
    import eel
    
    # Set web files folder
    eel.init('web')
    
    @eel.expose                         # Expose this function to Javascript
    def say_hello_py(x):
        print('Hello from %s' % x)
    
    say_hello_py('Python World!')
    eel.say_hello_js('Python World!')   # Call a Javascript function
    
    eel.start('hello.html', size=(300, 200))  # Start
```

**web/index.html**

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <head>
        <title>Hello, World!</title>
    
        <!-- Include eel.js - note this file doesn't exist in the 'web' directory -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/eel.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
          eel.expose(say_hello_js); // Expose this function to Python
          function say_hello_js(x) {
            console.log("Hello from " + x);
          }
    
          say_hello_js("Javascript World!");
          eel.say_hello_py("Javascript World!"); // Call a Python function
        </script>
      </head>
    
      <body>
        Hello, World!
      </body>
    </html>
```

Could it be that I have a wrong version of python or Eel? I am running Python 3.8.10. I ran `pip install eel --upgrade` but the issue still occurs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I cannot pin point the exact issue based on the details you provided. But you can try the following these steps if you're using VSC:

1. Run this command `py -m venv .venv` and it will create your virtual environment.
2. Select the virtual environment's Python interpreter with `CTRL` + `SHIFT` + `K`.
3. Close out your terminal with the trash icon.
4. Start the terminal using the virtual environment's Python interpreter with `CTRL` + `J`.
5. Run the command `pip install eel`.
6. Create the file `hello.py`.
7. Create the directory `web`.
8. In `web` create the file `hello.html`.

In `hello.py` use this code:

```
import eel
eel.init('web')
eel.say_hello_js('Hi from Python')
eel.start('hello.html')
```

In `hello.html` use this code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Hello, World!</title>

    <!-- Include eel.js - note this file doesn't exist in the 'web' directory -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/eel.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      eel.expose(say_hello_js); // Expose this function to Python
      function say_hello_js(x) {
        alert("Hello from " + x);
      }
    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    Hello, World!
  </body>
</html>
```

If you followed these steps, you should see the alert box pop up. To trigger a JS function from Python you need to precede the function with the eel expose function like this `eel.expose(your_js_function_name);`. From Python you would call this function using the eel module and calling that function name like this `eel.your_js_function_name(parameter_if_any)`. Make sure that in your HTML file you have the eel script element in the head. Then another script element after that one with all your functions.

Answer (score 0):

Even this was not the issue in this topic a stumbling block might be that you must **not** have a space between `eel.expose` and the `()`

```
eel.expose(function_name); // working
eel.expose (function_name); // not working, results in "module 'eel' has no attribute 'function_name' error on python side
```